# mobicent media server configuration issues

Tags: java, mobicents, mobicents-sip-servlets

I need help for the following scenario,

Mobicent Sip Servlet(mss-3.0.564-jboss-as-7.2.0) is installed in 192.168.0.121 and I want to run the example application media-jsr309-servlet. Mobicent mediaserver-3.0.0.Final is installed in 192.168.0.124. What modification I need to run that application with those two different IP addresses.

I have to use Mobicent Media server for my work. [image]

Answer (score 1):

As informed by Nafiz at Google Groups, the expected result was reached by replacing the IP addresses manually in media-jsr309-servlet, as a simple String.

Original post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobicents-public/_mhGbp27hO4